# Mail is redirecting to my app after it has been used to open my app on android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, intentfilter

I implemented filter-activity to open my app from url in e-mail and pass url to it. It works fine on the 1st trail: I open email, touch the link in e-mail, it asks me which app to use, I select my app and it goes fine.

However, now when I try opening Mail app again, to say open other e-mails, Mail app does not let me see e-mail it just brings me directly to my app without any data from the e-mail. I have to force quit my app to be able to open Mail again.

I tried GMail App with my app, it does not do that, it works as supposed to, i.e. takes me always to see e-mails. I wonder if there is something I missed so Android Mail app gets messed up.

Thanks.

here is filter from manifest file:

```
< intent-filter>
            < action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            < category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            < category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            < data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost.com"/>
< /intent-filter>

in the app i pull url like this:

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri!=null){
        String msgFromUrl=intent.getDataString();
        try {
            msgFromUrl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(msgFromUrl, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(msgFromUrl.length()>0){
            Toast.makeText(this, msgFromUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       }
  ...
}
```